# Find the area of this quadrilateral using double integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, definite-integrals

Evaluate this double integral:

$\int \int _{R} x dx dy$ where $R$ is the area of a quadrilateral of vertex $(0,-1),(5,-1),(3,1),(2,1).$

When i do the double integral i get the answer $15$. In the solution the answer is also $15$. What i don't understand is why when i calculate the area of this quadrilateral using basic geometry, I get an area of $6$. Am I doing something wrong here? Is it normal to get different answer?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your integral finds is the volume under the surface $z = x$ above your quadrilateral. If you wanted to find the area of your domain (the quadrilateral) use $z = 1$ as your integrand.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that the integral you evaluated doesn't give the area of the quadrilateral $R$. Indeed, called $A$ its area, you have
$$\int\int_R dx dy=A$$
and
$$\int\int_R x dx dy\neq \int\int_R dx dy.$$

Comment: The region isn’t a square. It’s a quadrilateral.

Comment: what are we evaluating then?

Comment: @spexel You could interpret the integral as computing the mass of a quadrilateral lamina that has increasing density to the right.

Comment: Moment of inertia around the $y$-axis (of a uniformly dense quadrilateral)?  Oops, that'd be the second moment of mass; this is the first moment.  I'm not sure what the physical interpretation of this quantity would be.

Comment: @BrianTung see TacoTesseract’s answer for another physical interpretation of the integral.

Comment: It's a bit contrived, but I think that's as good as we're going to get. ;-)